Is "thinking" out loud considered a Hefsek (interruption)?
Let's say someone was making a calculation in his head, and while doing so he uttered a part of his calculation verbally, is it considered a Hefsek, if he did so between Shel-Yad and Shel-Rosh, or is speaking only considered a Hefsek (interruption) either if one spoke to somebody else, or as a prayer or some other Mitzva?

I have a similar question about talking to devices

As I understand it ANY speaking is a hefsek (interruption).
To quote the Shulchan Aruch HaRav  בְּלִי שׁוּם הֶפְסֵק דִּבּוּר is the key phrase

For this reason, the Sages ordained that one put on the head-tefillin
directly after putting on the arm-tefillin without making any
interruption by speaking in the interim. In this way, the blessing
recited for the arm-tefillin applies also to the head-tefillin.


I think this is right, but theoretically you could question whether speaking to yourself is really considered speaking.
